# OpenCV (4.7) build on Ubuntu (22.04) with CUDA - OpenCV module python3 is unavailable, no bindings built

Tags: python, opencv, build

I'm building `OpenCV 4.7` from source with CUDA and cuDNN support.
I managed to install `CUDA 11.6` and `cuDNN 8.4` on my system, build OpenCV, and install it.

Despite setting all the flags for `Python3 (3.10)` and trying to configure it, it doesn't build the bindings for it.

**Confirmed that the library works with C++ and GPU support.**

[CMAKE GUI PYTHON FLAGS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7naY0.png)
(Redacted the username)

```
BUILD_opencv_python_bindings_generator = ON
OPENCV_PYTHON_VERSIION = ON
PYTHON3_EXECUTABLE = /usr/bin/python3.10
PYTHON3_INCLUDE_DIR = /usr/include/python3.10
PYTHON3_LIBRARY = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.10.so
PYTHYON3_NUMPY_INCLUDE_DIRS = /home/USERNAME/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/include
PYTHON3_PACKAGES_PATH = /home/USERNAME/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages
```

Part of resulting configuration:

```
Extra modules:
    Location (extra):            /home/USERNAME/Downloads/opencv/opencv_contrib-4.7.0/modules
    Version control (extra):     unknown

OpenCV modules:
    To be built:                 aruco barcode bgsegm bioinspired calib3d ccalib core cudaarithm
 cudabgsegm cudacodec cudafeatures2d cudafilters cudaimgproc cudalegacy cudaobjdetect cudaoptflow
 cudastereo cudawarping cudev datasets dnn ... A LOT MORE ... xphoto
    Disabled:                    freetype
    Disabled by dependency:      -
    Unavailable:                 alphamat ... ovis python2 python3 sfm viz
    Applications:                tests perf_tests examples apps
    Documentation:               NO
    Non-free algorithms:         NO


NVIDIA CUDA:                   YES (ver 11.6, CUFFT CUBLAS)
    NVIDIA GPU arch:             80 86
    NVIDIA PTX archs:

  cuDNN:                         YES (ver 8.4.0)

  Python (for build):            /usr/bin/python3.10
```

Being quite a newbie to such a detailed process, I'm out of ideas why it doesn't detect python properly.

Tried many combinations of the paths to the packages directory either in .local or /usr/lib/ (for my install pip seems to install packages to ***.local/lib/python/site-packages***).

Comment: How are you checking for the python bindings? When I built OpenCV, the python buildings were *built* with the python I provided, but the bindings themselves were isolated in the opencv build/ folder, where I would need to pip install from myself after the fact

Comment: According to almost every single resource, even official tutorials, it should work out of the box after calling `sudo make install`. I did notice a dir in the build folder `python_loader` (or something along those lines I'll edit the comment when I get back home) that contains a `cv2` dir and a `setup.py` file. I expected the cmake configuration to contain a section for Python3. Noticed that a flag was completely missing `BUILD_opencv_python3`, could that be a CMake caching issue?

Comment: That doesn't sound right to me. `make install` only builds the bindings, it doesn't install it into your environment for you. Think about it: if you wanted opencv in two different python environments, do you think it makes to re-build all of opencv? If you see a `setup.py` file, why can't you just take the extra step and run it. It's not worth trying to figure out why cmake isn't doing what you want